# php, curl, how to parse a rss feed with errors?

Tags: php, curl, rss

i have a rss feed and it seems that has some errors in it:

`http://api2.socialmention.com/search?q=acting+auditions&t=all&f=rss`

but if you look in the source file it will show you the entire code.

My question is: is ther a way of grabing that code and parsing it again to a useful feed?

The feed will take a while to show up

any ideas help,
Thanks

Comment: The feed you've provided [http://api2.socialmention.com/search?q=acting+auditions&t=all&f=rss](http://api2.socialmention.com/search?q=acting+auditions&t=all&f=rss) is a valid feed and I couldn't find any error on it. Please check if the feed is valid at http://validator.w3.org/feed/ before your post your questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running it through [tidy](http://php.net/tidy) may give you a well-formed feed, but I'd recommend talking to the provider in any case, they probably don't intend it to be broken.